# Fortran real variable with parentheses

Tags: variables, fortran, declaration

I am reading a Fortran code but I don't understand the real*8 variable declaration with parentheses like.

real*8::xxx21(2,3)

I know real*8 means but what is the meaning of (2,3), its parentheses?

I have tried the similar one from web but no many information there.

Comment: I did not find any exact duplte of this question, but it is really very basic. You would find examples of this in many questions here. Almost every Fortran code uses arrays. You will not get far without learning some Fortan first. Find some tutorial or textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax denotes an array of shape 2 times 3.

I highly suggest you to learn the basics of the language before trying to understand any code.

Comment: Do you mean that it is 2 by 3 matrix? -> 2 rows and 3 columns. Is this the same as "real*8, dimension (2 : 3) :: xxx21"?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. It is not a matrix, it is an array. There are no matrices in Fortran.

Comment: Ok I see. This is a different syntax of that, real*8, dimension(2:3)::xxx21. Thank you Vladimir.

Comment: Please also note real*8 is not and has never been standard Fortran

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark D'oh, indeed, I completely missed the `:` in the comment. `,` and `:` is very different. I just saw 2 by 3 matrix and not the `:`.

Comment: I prefer the "REAL, DIMENSION(2,3) ::" or  "REAL, DIMENSION(1:2,1:3) ::", where the later example make the "1:" redundant... basically because it is more readable. Choose 1 way and stick with it.